# Wordpress Change URL after Migrating to Amazon EC2

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am doing migration of Wordpress from one Amazon EC2 instance to another Amazon EC2 instance after it is messed up. So I did the installation of LAMP from the AWS documentation. I have moved my Wordpress contents into `/var/www/html`. I have also prepared the database accordingly and run the `.sql` backup file.

But then when I go to the IP address, it just could not load. My guess is the current Wordpress is using the old IP of the instance while I now have a new IP for the new instance. How do I fix this?

So far what I did to get access into the website:

Based on https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL I have put below code in my `wp-config.php` file

```
define('WP_HOME','http://X.X.X.X');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://X.X.X.X');
```

But it did not work. Any guidance is highly appreciated. Thank you.

UPDATE:

Sorry for being unclear about the observation. Says my old IP was http://1.1.1.1, and my new IP is http://1.1.1.2. After the changes, when I try to go to http://1.1.1.2, it just like take some times to load then suddenly it tries to bring me back to http://1.1.1.1. And of course eventually I'll receive time out error message because old IP is no longer available.

I am using Apache web server, latest Wordpress 4.5, http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/hosting-wordpress.html#wordpress-troubleshooting

Comment: Hi @UserProg, thanks for your question. It's very clear, but I think you miss to explain what webserver (Apache, NGINX?) are you using and if there is any problem with it. Also, you should tell us about what error do you get when you try to access. Saying "did not work" is not a good debug output. Looking forward to heard about your webserver.

Comment: @HéctorValverdePareja thanks, see my updated question.

Comment: Double check your .htaccess file.

Comment: @edwardjiang7 i could not locate the `.htaccess` file in `/var/www/html`. Maybe it is hidden. How do I locate it (if it is hidden) and edit it?

Comment: @edwardjiang7 I have found my `.htaccess` file in the backup folder and it contains the old IP. Maybe it is not moved to `/var/www/html` because it is hidden. Do I need to copy and paste into `/var/www/html`?

Comment: Yes, move it to your WordPress directory.

Comment: I guess you get a 302 response from the new IP and timeout from second. You surely can fix it changing redirects in .htaccess.

Comment: OK so I did move the `.htaccess` to `html` folder but the same thing is still happening :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to find the workaround after adding the `.htaccess` file. To summarize, here are what I did:

1. Put the `define` function in `wp-config.php`
2. change WordPress site URL with the wp-cli with the help of AWS documentation http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/hosting-wordpress.html#wordpress-troubleshooting
3. Put back the `.htaccess` file into `/var/www/html` and change the previous IP to current IP

Last thing I did that does the magic was **clear cache in the browser**. And finally my website now could be opened. Thank you for the comments above and that really help.